# Workflow not working when called by another script

Tags: powershell, workflow

I have a script, let's call it **A.ps1** that uses a workflow called **Copy-Parallel** (the workflow is defined in the beginning of the script). I created a **GUI.ps1** script that I use to easily select between multiple scripts, it calls the desired script with "Start-Process". In the end I created a shortcut, so I could run the GUI by double-click.

All resources are located on a server and the two scripts are in the same folder called **Res**. The shortcut is located in the same folder as **Res**. When we use the shortcut, the script works fine for me but other users get the: *term 'Copy-Parallel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...* error.

We tried to run the **A.ps1** script directly and it works fine for me and other users. We tried running the **GUI.ps1** via a .bat file, the results were similar to the ones when we used the shortcut.

**A.ps1:**

```
workflow Copy-Parallel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [array]
        $Files,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]
        $Destination

    )   
    foreach -parallel -throttlelimit 20 ($File in $Files) {
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $File -Destination $Destination -Force
    }
}
Copy-Parallel -Files $SourceFiles.FullName -Destination $DestinationPath
```

**GUI.ps1** calls the script as follows:

```
$ScriptToRun = "$PSScriptRoot\A.ps1"
Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList $ScriptToRun -NoNewWindow
```

The target for the shortcut that starts the GUI is: *%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File "Res\GUI.ps1"*

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Power Shell looks for cmdlets using the Environmental Variable PSModulePath.  A cmdlet will first look for the ps1 file in the current folder and if it does not find the script it then searches the PSModulePath.